# not authorized on chatcatappdb to execute command in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm beginner in NodeJs and Mongoose.I tried to retrieved the data from db.

```html
   db.userchatdetails.findOne({'profileId':profileId},(err,result)=>{

            if(err){
                console.log(`Error at the finding user ${err}`);  //ERROR OCCURED IN THIS LINE
                
            }
            else{
                console.log(`User found in db`);
                
            }
        });
```

**Error:**

**Error at the finding user MongoError:** **not authorized on chatcatappdb to execute command** { find: "userchats", filter: { profileId: "109929376697848" }, limit: 1, batchSize: 1, singleBatch: true, $db: "chatcatappdb" }
(node:19260) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2):

I'm using Robomongo and Mlab.I have connected mlab link to robomongo.It's connected successfully.

I have searched in internet I have executed some comments.

> db.auth("username", "password")
>
> db.grantRolesToUser("username", [ { role: "read", db: "databasename" } ])

but Eventhough it's not working.

Comment: `db.grantRolesToUser("username", [ { role: "read", db: "databasename" } ])` in place of `database` you wrote `chatcatappdb` right?

Comment: yes I have written samething