# SyntaxError: Unexpected token function in async function?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, async-await

Hi everyone I'm beginner in Nodejs and mongoose.I have tried to insert and retrieve the data in mongoose.I'm using **async await** function to **execute one by one (sequence)**.can anyone help me? Thanks in advance....

i.e: I want to execute (Async await)concept (SEQUENCE STEP)

1.connect the db

2.create the user

3.find the user.

I'm getting the error :

```html
async function calltaskone(){
      ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:78:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:543:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:420:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:139:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:535:3
    
    
    Code for your reference:
    
    
    'use strict';

const mongoose=require('mongoose');


const calldbconnect=()=>{
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        if(true){
            mongoose.connect('mongodb://vdsd:vdwdwh12dw3,@ds11dwdw.mlab.com:1w5664/vorganisation',{useNewUrlParser:true},(err,db)=>{
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                    reject('Db is not connected');
                }
                else{
                    resolve('Db is connected');
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

const schemadesign=new mongoose.Schema({
    clientName:String,
    clientId:Number,
    clientAddress:String
});


const modeldata=mongoose.model('clientInfo',schemadesign);

const data=[{
    clientName:'VIGNESH Mack',
    clientId:4128,
    clientAddress:'UK'
},{
    clientName:'VIGNESH Tokyo',
    clientId:4988,
    clientAddress:'USA'
}];

function calldatasave(){

    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{

        modeldata.create(data,(err,a,b)=>{
            if(err){
                reject(`Error occured while data saved ${err}`);
            }
            else{
                resolve('Data saved successfully');
            }
        });
           
    });
}

const calldatafind=()=>{

    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{

        if(true){
            console.log('try to find');
            modeldata.find({'clientId':4988},(err,data)=>{
                if(err){
                    reject(`Error occured while find data: ${err}`)
                }
                else{
                    console.log(data);
                    resolve('Data found');
                }
            });
        }  
    });
}

async function calltaskone(){

    const a=await calldbconnect();
    console.log(a);
    const b=await calldatasave();
    console.log(b);
    const c=await calldatafind();
    console.log(c);

}

calltaskone();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're using a older version of Node. Async functions are not supported by Node versions older than version 7.6. You can check [here](https://node.green/).

If you want to use async/await then you need to transpile using `Babel` for your node version.

Edit:

As you said you are using `v7.3`, you can use (from v7.0 to v7.5) the `--harmony` flag to enable the experimental features. To know more about the flag, check this out: [What does `node --harmony` do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13351965/what-does-node-harmony-do)

Comment: I'm using node 7.3.0 version

Comment: yeah, that's what I said. You need 7.6 and above to use `async/await`. You're Node version 7.3.0 doesn't support `async/await`. In your case you can use the `--harmony` flag. I am editing the answer.

Comment: will you refer this error: I'm struggling for past two days:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53503696/not-authorized-on-chatcatappdb-to-execute-command-in-mongoose

Comment: dude just upgrade your node version or use the --harmony flag.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53503696/not-authorized-on-chatcatappdb-to-execute-command-in-mongoose